# Why Web3 event callback fires multiple times same as the number of the solidity smart contract emitted that event in past?

Tags: solidity, web3js, react, web3js-v1.x

I am just learning, solidity with react and web3 and I am facing the issue on page load the callback event of web3 called multiple time the number is same as I called a solidity function and that emit that event in past.

Smart Contact:-

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Institute{
struct InstituteDetails {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint studentCount;
}


mapping(uint => InstituteDetails) public Institutes;

constructor() public{
    addInstitute('test');
}

event instituteCreatedEvent (
    uint  id
);
 // Store Candidates Count
uint public instituteCount;

function addInstitute (string memory _name) public {
    instituteCount ++;
    Institutes[instituteCount] = InstituteDetails(instituteCount, 
_name, 0);
    emit instituteCreatedEvent(instituteCount);
}
}
```

React component

```
    import React,  { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button, Modal, Table, thead, tr, th, td, tbody } from "react-bootstrap";

import TruffleContract from 'truffle-contract'
import Institute from '../abis/Institute.json'
import web3Data from'./SharingData'

function Homepage(props){
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [instituteName, setInstitute] = useState(false);
  const [instituteList, setInstituteList] = useState([]);
  const [instituteInstance, setInstituteInstance] = useState();
  const institute = TruffleContract(Institute)
  institute.setProvider(web3Data.web3Provider)

  useEffect(() => {
  },[instituteList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.web3.eth.getCoinbase((err, account) => {
      institute.deployed().then((instituteObj) => {
        setInstituteInstance(instituteObj);
          watchEvents(instituteObj)
      })
    })
  },[]);

  const watchEvents  = async (instituteObj)=> {
    console.log(instituteObj.allEvents);
    instituteObj.instituteCreatedEvent({
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
    }, async (error,result) => {
      if(result&& result.args.id){
        const InstitutesArray = [];
         for (var i = 1; i <= result.args.id.toNumber(); i++) {
          await instituteObj.Institutes(i).then((instObj) => {
            InstitutesArray.push({
              id: instObj[0].toNumber(),
              name: instObj[1],
              studentCount: instObj[2].toNumber()
            });
          });
        }
        setInstituteList(InstitutesArray);
      }
      else if(result&& !result.args.id){
      }
    })
  }

  const handleClose = (isSubmitted) => {
    setShow(false);
    setInstitute('');
    if(isSubmitted && instituteInstance){
      instituteInstance.addInstitute(instituteName,{ from: props.account });
    }
  }
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const nameChange = (e) => {
    setInstitute(e.target.value);
  }

  const InstituteListComp =[];
  console.log('instituteList.length', instituteList.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < instituteList.length; i++) {
    InstituteListComp.push(<tr key={'key'+i}>
      <td>{instituteList[i].id}</td>
      <td>{instituteList[i].name}</td>
      <td>{instituteList[i].studentCount}</td>
    </tr>)
   };

    return (
      <div className="Homepage">
      <h1>Welcome in BlockChain IMS</h1>

      <Table striped bordered hover> 
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      {InstituteListComp}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Create School
      </Button>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Create School</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body><input onChange={nameChange} /></Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=>handleClose(true)}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save 
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }

Homepage.propTypes = {
  Homepage: PropTypes.func,
  isError: PropTypes.bool,
  web3: PropTypes.object,
  account: PropTypes.string,
};
export default Homepage;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question here.

Comment: Please check now I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are watching the events from

```xml
fromBlock: 0,
```

to

```xml
toBlock: 'latest'
```

so it seems logical it will fire for all the past events.
It you only want recent events you can change the fromBlock.

Comment: Yes I changed 'toBlack' value to 'latest' it's working, thank you so much.